# Create n instances of item in list and concatenate a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create 5 instances of each item in a list, and for each of those, concatenate a string up till the value '5'.

```
my_list=['A','B','C']
scores=[]
n=0
for i in my_list:
    scores.append([my_list[n]]*5)
    n+=1
print(scores)
```

Output

```
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']]
```

```
scores_list=[]
n=1
for list_of_lists in scores:
    while n<6:
        scores_list.append(scores[0][0]+'_'+str(n))
        n+=1
print(scores_list)
```

Output

```
['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5']
```

Expected

```
[['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5'], ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3', 'B_4', 'B_5'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5']]
```

I've tried using more while loops but can't think of anything else. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're referencing `scores[0][0]`, so it adds `scores[0][0]`

Comment: True. Disregard my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Let's focus on your current programming level.  A simple loop nesting will do the job.  The value that changes the fastest, goes on the inside loop:

```
scores = []
for letter in "ABC":
    list_5 = []
    for number in range(1, 6):
        list_5.append(letter + '_' + str(number))

    scores.append(list_5)

print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5'], ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3', 'B_4', 'B_5'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [[f"{char}_{num+1}" for num in range(5)] for char in my_list]
[['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5'], ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3', 'B_4', 'B_5'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the original code is that you never reset the value of n back to one after the first iteration. but you can even skip the `n` variable by:

```
my_list=['A','B','C']
duplications = 5
scores=[]
for i in my_list:
    scores.append([f'{i}_{n}' for n in range(1, duplications+1)])
print(scores)
```

Output:

```
[['A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3', 'A_4', 'A_5'], ['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3', 'B_4', 'B_5'], ['C_1', 'C_2', 'C_3', 'C_4', 'C_5']]
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use my code. It's very simple.

```
my_list=['A','B','C']

scores=[[f"{c}_{i+1}" for i in range(5)] for c in my_list]

print(scores)
```

Comment: Using `product` loses the nested list that the OP expects.

Comment: Otherwise, `product(my_list, index_list)` is sufficient; you don't need to build a list only to immediately unpack it.

Comment: `product` can also use `range(1,6)` directly; you don't need to create a list first.

Comment: Uhhm... How is this different than [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63710274/9608759)?